# Add a row in a table below the row in which the add button click using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table below which having the the 'Add' button in every row. I want when I click on the add button the row should be added below that specific row where I click ADD button.

```
<table id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <th><button class="add">Add</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <th><button class="add">Add</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <th><button class="add">Add</button>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used the below JS. Using index but now working as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add").click(function () {
        var row_index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        html = "<td>Adam</td><td>'Puja'</td><td>30</td><td><button 
        class='add'>Add</button></td>";
        ("#table_id > tbody > tr").eq(row_index+1).after(html);
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Addrow(e){
     var row_index = $(e).closest("tr").index()-1;
     html = "<tr><td>Adam</td><td>'Puja'</td><td>30</td><td><button class='add'>Add</button></td></tr>";
     $('#table_id  > tbody > tr').eq(row_index+1).after(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <th><button class="add" onclick="Addrow(this)">Add</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <th><button class="add" onclick="Addrow(this)">Add</button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <th><button class="add" onclick="Addrow(this)">Add</button>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this code.